# extra jar in war in a maven project

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

One business jar which have been developed by us is present in war. but I don't see in pom.xml.... when I search whole eclipse I found it is in .setting folder(.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component) of eclipse of same project.

here is entry of

```
<dependent-module archiveName="BankAccount-3.0.39.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" 
   handle="module:/classpath/var/M2_REPO/com/BankAccount/3.0.39/BankAccount-3.0.39.jar">
      <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is; are you asking why it's there? Is it a dependency of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that jar is not needed by your project, then run `mvn dependency:tree` and find the origin of the particular jar. Then you can exclude the jar by using

```
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
     <groupId>Group Id</groupId>
     <artifactId>jar which you want to exclude</artifactId>
   </exclusion>                     
</exclusions>
```

under the particular jar through which it got bundled.

You can also remove the jar by using the `<exclusion>` tag in assembly.xml of the particular project

Answer (score 0):

Do `mvn dependency:tree` and see how it works.